# How can I use MetadataAPI to add field visibility to a Permission Set (Using APEX)

Tags: apex, metadata-api, permission-sets

I'm creating a field dynamically via apex (or tooling API haven't decided yet) and my problem has been this field is created with no access level to anyone.

To overcome this I wanted to add the field to a permission set after it's created.

[I found the Financialforce examples and wanted to use something like this:](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)

```
@future(callout = true)

public static void testPerm()
{
    /* Find the Quick Toggler Permission Set! */
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
    String[] permissionSetNames = new String[] {'VA_Quick_Visibility_Toggler_Permissions'};
    List<MetadataService.PermissionSet> perm = 
        (List<MetadataService.PermissionSet>) service.readMetadata('PermissionSet', permissionSetNames).getRecords();
    MetadataService.PermissionSet quickPerm = perm.get(0);
    
    MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions fieldSec = new MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions();
    fieldSec.field='User.TestFieldA__c';
    fieldSec.editable=true;
    fieldSec.readable=true;
    quickPerm.fieldPermissions.add(fieldSec);
    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =
        service.updateMetadata(
            new MetadataService.Metadata[] { quickPerm });
    handleSaveResults(results[0]);
    
}
```

And that code needs these two methods.

```
public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService()
{
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
    return service;
}

/**
 * Example helper method to interpret a SaveResult, throws an exception if errors are found
 **/
public static void handleSaveResults(MetadataService.SaveResult saveResult)
{
    // Nothing to see?
    if(saveResult==null || saveResult.success)
        return;
    // Construct error message and throw an exception
    if(saveResult.errors!=null)
    {
        List<String> messages = new List<String>();
        messages.add(
            (saveResult.errors.size()==1 ? 'Error ' : 'Errors ') +
                'occured processing component ' + saveResult.fullName + '.');
        for(MetadataService.Error error : saveResult.errors)
            messages.add(
                error.message + ' (' + error.statusCode + ').' +
                ( error.fields!=null && error.fields.size()>0 ?
                    ' Fields ' + String.join(error.fields, ',') + '.' : '' ) );
        if(messages.size()>0)
            throw new MetadataServiceExamplesException(String.join(messages, ' '));
    }
    if(!saveResult.success)
        throw new MetadataServiceExamplesException('Request failed with no specified error.');
}
```

I'm getting unknown errors though. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Update: getting the API name made me realize that the permission set already has field permissions and the code was attempting to replace the permissions with only the 1 field permission, so fixed that. But I'm still getting Read Timeouts!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass API name of the permission set here and it work fine. API name can be found in the permission set page itself.

[image]

```
    String[] permissionSetNames = new String[] {'Survey_Force_Guest'};
```

I have tried this many times and it works without any errors.

Comment: I tried with the API name but I still get a timeout error everytime